# Only able to paste string values to a Flask WTF-Forms field

Tags: python, flask, flask-wtforms

I am trying to have a view function paste decimal values (eventually from a database) into a WTF form field. The value does not show up unless I change the field to a string field. Do I need something extra to paste a numerical value into a decimal field?

I have created a small, hopefully reproducible example to test this functionality only. It has a single field which, upon loading the page, should paste a value in the field.

Originally I tried this with a decimal field, and tried pasting a random number, but that number doesn't show up when the page is rendered. The same happens when the field is changed to an IntegerField or FloatField

When changing the form field to a string field, the value will show up upon page rendering - however this is not an ideal solution since the value will be a string.

**routes.py**

```
from flask import render_template, flash
from app import app
from app.forms import TestForm

@app.route('/',methods=['GET','POST'])
@app.route('/index/',methods=['GET','POST'])
def index():
    # define form
    test_form = TestForm()

    test_form.testfield.data = 10

    return render_template('sandbox_home.html',
        test_form = test_form
        )
```

**forms.py**

```
from flask_wtf import FlaskForm
from wtforms import StringField,DecimalField

class TestForm(FlaskForm):
    testfield=StringField()
```

**sandbox_home.html**

```html
<!doctype html>

<title>My Safe Place</title>

<p>I exist to paste values to form fields!</p>

<form action="" method="post" novalidate>  
  {{ test_form.hidden_tag() }}
  {{ test_form.testfield() }}
</form>
```

I would expect the value to show up regardless of the field type, if the input is of the correct type. I am guessing this is a datatype issue, but I'm not sure where the issue is.

Comment: I just tested and it works perfectly. Can you tell which version of `FLASK` and `flask_wtf` you use? Did you take into account the `CamelCase` ? `IntegerField` and not `Integerfield` ?

Comment: @Tobin I am using `Flask 1.1.1` and `flask_wtf 0.14.2` which it looks like those are the most updated versions. I just tried again with `IntegerField` and double checked the `CamelCase` with the same result (nothing populating the field).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a minimal example that shows this working OK:

```py
from flask import Flask, render_template_string
from flask_wtf import FlaskForm
from wtforms import StringField, IntegerField, DecimalField


app = Flask(__name__)
app.secret_key = ";lskjflksdjflsdkjfsd;lghdi9uawhj"


class TestForm(FlaskForm):
    test_str = StringField()
    test_int = IntegerField()
    test_dec = DecimalField()


template = """
<!doctype html>

<title>My Safe Place</title>

<p>I exist to paste values to form fields!</p>

<form action="" method="post" novalidate>
  {{ test_form.hidden_tag() }}
  {{ test_form.test_str() }}
  {{ test_form.test_int() }}
  {{ test_form.test_dec() }}
</form>
"""


if __name__ == "__main__":
    # simulate handling a request
    with app.test_request_context():
        test_form = TestForm()
        test_form.test_str.data = 10
        test_form.test_int.data = 10
        test_form.test_dec.data = 10

        # render the template and save to file so can open in browser
        with open("test.html", "w") as f:
            f.write(render_template_string(template, test_form=test_form))
```

It saves the rendered template to a file called `test.html` which looks like this:

```html
<!doctype html>

<title>My Safe Place</title>

<p>I exist to paste values to form fields!</p>

<form action="" method="post" novalidate>
  <input id="csrf_token" name="csrf_token" type="hidden" value="IjUyMDI2NDYxMDY2OTc3N2E0OTU3ODYwM2M0Y2RiMzNjYjY5OWZlMDAi.XcXs_g.55IiutLhjhC2h7J9MI8rWtNu9co">
  <input id="test_str" name="test_str" type="text" value="10">
  <input id="test_int" name="test_int" type="text" value="10">
  <input id="test_dec" name="test_dec" type="text" value="10.00">
</form>
```

And here is screenshot of that in the browser:

[image]

As you can see from the rendered template, WTForms doesn't differentiate between the different types of fields in the browser (i.e., they are all `type="text"`). If you can let me know how to modify this script to reproduce your error I'm happy to look at it again.

Comment: thank you for the detailed response. I modified my code a bit adding in all three types at one time (decimal, string, and integer). After restarting my local server it worked! I'm...not sure where the error was (potentially restarting the server, although I did that several times before), but will try to dig into it a little more.

Comment: Have you been running your local server in debug mode so that code changes are automatically reloaded? Perhaps your perception of inconsistent behavior stems from that not happening?